# Request Mapping returning error 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

This is my controller that maps a request to this url `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCJSON/rest/kfc/brands`

**contoller file**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfc/brands")
public class JSONController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[] { "name1", "name2" });

        return shop;

    }
```

this is the web.xml with the servlet request that dispatches the request/response along with the url

```
<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Assuming that everything is alright, when I launch my app on this url it returns error 404 `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCJSON/rest/kfc/brands`
My server console returns this warning

```
Apr 26, 2016 12:14:47 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCJSON/rest/kfc/brands] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Please why is tomcat not mapping request to the server?

Comment: Any [spring] caretakers around here? Almost 300 identical questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22No+mapping+found+for+HTTP+request+with+URI%22+%22in+DispatcherServlet+with+name%22 and at first sight no canonical duplicate yet. This creates too much the impression that [spring] isn't it worth to curate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configured your controller to be available on `/kfc/brands/{name}` URL but trying to access it on `/kfc/brands`.

Here you can find more information about using `@RequestMapping`: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: So if I remove this line @RequestMapping(value = "{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET) then everything should be fine?

Comment: Try to access by URL `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCJSON/rest/kfc/brands/test` first and test if it works.